# Upgrade Spark in DSE (DataStax Enterprise) 4.6

Tags: apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

Is it possible in [DSE 4.6](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/RNdse46.html) to upgrade [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and the corresponding [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) from version 1.1.0 to the most recent 1.2.0.

DSE currently ships with Spark and Spark Cassandra Connector 1.1.0 only.

Answer (score 2):

#### **Short Answer:**

You will have to wait for a future version for Spark 1.2 to be included in and supported by DSE.

#### Alternatively:

You can use DSE's Cassandra with your own Spark 1.2 setup a la [Al Tobey](http://tobert.github.io/post/2014-07-15-installing-cassandra-spark-stack.html)

#### **At your own risk:**

I did successfully upgrade the connector to a newer version in a previous version of DSE (I think it was .9 to 1.0--you would have to edit the versions and dependencies for 1.2). These are the steps I followed (**do this at your own risk, do not attempt in a production setting**):

Using the following bash script, create your connector jars (run this as sudo so that the mkdir works):

```
mkdir /opt/connector
cd /opt/connector

rm *.jar

curl -o ivy-2.3.0.jar   'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.3.0/ivy-2.3.0.jar'
curl -o spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.1.0-beta2.jar 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/datastax/spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.1.0-beta2/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.1.0-beta2.jar'

ivy () { java -jar ivy-2.3.0.jar -dependency $* -retrieve "[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"; }

ivy org.apache.cassandra cassandra-thrift 2.0.11
ivy com.datastax.cassandra cassandra-driver-core 2.0.6
ivy joda-time joda-time 2.3
ivy org.joda joda-convert 1.6

rm -f *-{sources,javadoc}.jar
```

Next find your spark lib directory, in my case it's `/usr/local/lib/dse/resources/spark/lib/`

and copy all the jars you just generated into that directory. Then rename or remove the old connector (keep it around as a backup).

Restart DSE and start spark-shell:

```
dse spark
```

To verify which connector is loaded use:

```
dse spark -verbose
```

Naturally, you'll have to do this for every node.

**Note:** I have not actually attempted upgrading the Spark version. It might be a matter of changing the jar but I have not tried it. If you feel like hacking give it a try and let us know!

Comment: Hi, and thank you for answering. Can you tell me, what exactly happens on line 11-14? How do I know what artifacts I have to list there? Simply [all](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10/1.1.0-beta2) the dependencies?

Comment: Per Al Tobey's post "while ivy can download the connector directly, it will end up pulling down all of Cassandra and Spark. The script fragment below pulls down only what is necessary to run the connector against a pre-built Spark."

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try tomorrow. Btw do you also have experience in upgrading the cassandra-stress tool on DSE? I figured out the `stress.jar` file is located in `/usr/share/dse/cassandra/tools/lib/` though simply replacing the JAR with the most recent one doesn't work (command will fail with message 'no arguments specified' no matter what arguments are given).

Comment: Can you make a separate post for stress? tl; dr you can download C* 2.1 and run it from there. Just make sure DSE is running on your local or you point to one of your nodes with the -h flag.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, unfortunately [it failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346033/stress-cassandra-instance-on-ec2-from-local).

Comment: Check out my response in your new post